# How can I sort ascending and descending div with numbers when clicked?

Tags: html, jquery, sorting

I have a certain markup with different data. I would like to sort a certain block by numbers. However, the code below, which is more or less suitable for me, does not work as expected. Now it just changes the order of the rows in reverse to the current one without taking into account the Price column. Unfortunately, I could not achieve more.

I will be grateful for any help here)

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#tsection').on('click', '.thead .price', function () {
        var table = $('#tsection .tbody').eq(0);
        var price = table.find('.list_item .price').text().replace(/[^0-9]/gi, '');
        var rows = table.find('.list_item').toArray().sort(comparer($(price).index()))
        price.asc = !price.asc
        if (!price.asc) {
            rows = rows.reverse()
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            table.append(rows[i])
        }
    })

    function comparer(index) {
        return function (a, b) {
            var valA = getCellValue(a, index),
                valB = getCellValue(b, index)
            return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.toString().localeCompare(valB)
        }
    }

    function getCellValue(row, index) {
        return $(row).children('.list_item').eq(index).text()
    }
});
```

```css
.thead div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
}

.thead .price:after {
font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
font-weight: 900;
content: "\f0dc";
margin-left: 2px;
}

.tbody .list_item div {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.13/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section id="tsection">
    <div class="thead">
        <div class="name">Name</div>
        <div class="country">Country</div>
        <div class="price">Price</div> <!-- asc/desc sorting by digit -->
        <div class="time">Time</div>
    </div>

    <div class="tbody">
        <div class="list_item">
            <div class="name">Mark</div>
            <div class="country">USA</div>
            <div class="price">From 1 920 $</div> <!-- asc/desc sorting by digit -->
            <div class="time">9 months</div>
        </div>
        <div class="list_item">
            <div class="name">Piter</div>
            <div class="country">Colombia</div>
            <div class="price">2 220 $</div> <!-- asc/desc sorting by digit -->
            <div class="time">2,5 months</div>
        </div>
        <div class="list_item">
            <div class="name">Jacob</div>
            <div class="country">Israel</div>
            <div class="price">From 935 $</div> <!-- asc/desc sorting by digit -->
            <div class="time">4,7 months</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: What exactly is the issue? The code seems to be working fine - the order is changed by the price value correctly when clicking the 'Price' heading...? Also, why are you not using a `table` element for this?

Comment: I apologize. I changed the markup to make it clear that it doesn't work quite right.